# Access the value of .env variable via bash

Tags: bash

Here is my `.env`

```
APP_NAME=Admin
APP_URL=http://localhost:4202
JWT=secret12345
PORT=3002
```

If I run `cat .env | grep APP_URL` I got `APP_URL=http://localhost:4202`.

What do I need to run to get just the value `http://localhost:4202`?

*I'm sure, I can achieve that by exploding the string based on the `=` sign, and get it based on the second element of the array, but I'm hoping that there is a cleaner way to get that.*

Comment: `awk -F= '$1 == "APP_URL" {print $2}' .env`

Comment: @zwer, I can't do that, it is the .env file of my Laravel application.

Answer (score 2):

You could just *source* the file in a sub-shell and access the variable value directly. Using command-substitution would help you achieve that,

```
url=$(. ./.env; printf '%s' "$APP_URL")
```

Doing `. ./file` is a POSIX way to source the file to the shell being run, in our case within a sub-shell, since under a `$(..)` construct.

Answer (score 2):

You may use either of these 2 ways:

awk solution:

```
awk -F= '$1 == "APP_URL" {print $2}' .env
http://localhost:4202
```

or source this file in a sub-shell:

```
( source .env; echo "$APP_URL" )
http://localhost:4202
```

Comment: @kyo: If you want to store value in a variable then use: `app_url=$(awk -F= '$1 == "APP_URL" {print $2}' .env)`

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: source the file

```
$ source .env
$ echo "$APP_URL"
```

Option 2: grep and xargs

```
$ APP_URL=$(grep APP_URL .env | xargs)
$ APP_URL=${APP_URL#*=}
```

Comment: Your second suggestions show the whole row. I only need value.

Answer (score 1):

***Solution 1st:*** You could try importing it `. ./.env` into your box and then simply print `echo "$APP_URL"` and you should get the value then.

***Solution 2nd:*** In case you want to read it as Input_file then do following.

```
sed -n '/APP_URL/s/.*=//p'  .env
```

Comment: While this is good, doing it in the parent shell would affect the variable `APP_URL` if present, needs to be done in a sub-shell

Answer (score 1):

I am laravel user too. If you are executing the command in the base directory, execute the following command.

```
grep -e "APP_URL" /path/to/.env | awk -F= '{print $2}'
```

Try and let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: There is no need to use `grep` with `awk`, a simple `awk` could work here for you.

Comment: Yes, But if we can give filtering work to grep and processing work to awk, it will be good in long run :D